# How to get OAuth2 user information in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, adsense

I am trying to make an Adsense client for iOS, I already successfully created the OAuth login, but I have problems to get the user data, I used [simple-oauth2](https://github.com/Christian-Hansen/simple-oauth2) to authenticate the user. I can't see any method to get the user information to display it in the app. Can someone help me please?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17991298/1059705 might help you .. try this

Comment: Setting the scope to `googleapis.com/auth/adsense.readonly` is not only enough, after that you have to send a request with  ***`urlStr = @"https://www.googleapis.com/adsense/v1.1/adclients";`***

Comment: Kindly check this link ,[AdSense Management API v1.3 Services](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/adsense/v1.3/)