# Get User information after successful authentication with Oauth2

Tags: iphone, ios, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

In my iPhone app I am using google sign in using `Oauth2`, I am following [this insturction](https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction) and successfully login in

```
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * )viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication * )auth
                 error:(NSError * )error
{


if(!error)
    {
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success Authorizing with Google"

                                                         message:nil
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

I am using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile scope for `GTMOAuth2Authentication`, now I want to get user basic information like name,age,email,etc.

So how can I get the all detail??
I have searching lot but didn't find any thing.

Probably duplicate question of [How to get OAuth2 user information in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774918/how-to-get-oauth2-user-information-in-ios) , but it also doesn't help.

Please Help

Comment: you have to set signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserProfile to YES to your viewController. **`viewController.signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserProfile = YES;`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using this code

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/activities/public"];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [self.auth authorizeRequest:request
                      completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                          NSString *output = nil;
                          if (error) {
                              output = [error description];
                          } else {
                              // Synchronous fetches like this are a really bad idea in Cocoa applications
                              //
                              // For a very easy async alternative, we could use GTMHTTPFetcher
                              NSURLResponse *response = nil;
                              NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                                   returningResponse:&response
                                                                               error:&error];
                              if (data) {
                                  // API fetch succeeded
                                  output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;

                                  NSError* error;
                                  NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                                        JSONObjectWithData:data

                                                        options:kNilOptions
                                                        error:&error];



                                  NSArray *array=[json objectForKey:@"items"];
                                  if (array.count>0) {
                                      NSDictionary *dicts=[array objectAtIndex:0];

                                      //  NSLog(@"actor:%@",[dicts objectForKey:@"actor"]);
                                      //[self updateUI:[dicts objectForKey:@"actor"]];
                                      // [dictUserInfo setObject:[[[dicts objectForKey:@"actor"] objectForKey:@"image"]objectForKey:@"url"] forKey:@"imageUrl"];


                                      if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(userPicChanged:)])
                                      {
                                          //send the delegate function with the amount entered by the user
                                          [delegate userPicChanged:[[[dicts objectForKey:@"actor"] objectForKey:@"image"]objectForKey:@"url"]];
                                      }



                                  }


                              } else {
                                  // fetch failed
                                  output = [error description];
                              }
                          }
                      }];
```

Answer (score 5):

***By default, the GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch viewController will fetch the user's email, but not the rest of the user's profile.

The full profile can be requested from Google's server by setting this property before sign-in:***

`GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController;`
`viewController.signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserProfile = YES;`

***The profile will be available after sign-in as***

```
   NSDictionary *profile = viewController.signIn.userProfile;
```

and to get other information you have to change the `scope` string and begin fetch again.

here are some scope urls

`@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"`

`@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"`

`@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks"`

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried? and where you got stuck?

Comment: I must say, I had other issue of SDK showing 'Know who you are on Google'. Which my users doesn't want to see. So this same fix worked like charm . Thanks a ton +1