# iOS - Can't get basic user info from Google profile

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I want to retrieve basic information like name, email from Google account. Here [Get User information after successful authentication with Oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989853/get-user-information-after-successful-authentication-with-oauth2) I've found tip to change the property "shouldFetchGoogleUserProfile" to YES, but it's not accessible for me.

```
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController;
                viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scope
                                                            clientID:kMyClientID
                                                        clientSecret:kMyClientSecret
                                                    keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                            delegate:self
                                                     finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

// error - can't access property "shouldFetchGoogleUserProfile"
   viewController.signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserProfile = YES;

[[self navigationController] pushViewController: viewController
                                       animated:YES];
```

I cannot also get the result after sign-in

```
  - (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
  finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
             error:(NSError *)error {
 if (!error) {
      // userProfile - not accessible
     // NSDictionary *profile = viewController.signIn.userProfile;
  } else {
     NSLog(@"Failure %@", error);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Add

```
#import "GTL/GTMOAuth2SignIn.h"
```

to the bridging header which is the class for signIn.